# How to extract all the page source using Python/BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am trying to read data of a table from this website: https://cdn.ime.co.ir (like the table in the pic(you should click on each table's header to open it))
[image]
 but it seems using following code doesn't access to tables content! How can I read data of tables?

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://cdn.ime.co.ir'
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
result = soup.find()
print(result)
```

What I am looking for is the following html code that I found by `inspect element` but I can not see it in the `result` response variable I print in my code:

```
<table id="future" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" class="table table-bordered table-striped" ng-hide="num == $index" width="100%">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th colspan="9">
                                            <div class="pull-right">
                                                <span ng-click="showModal('md',fkey)" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-list"></i><b> مشخصات قرارداد</b></span>
                                            </div>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="bgHead" rowspan="2" title="Futures Contract" style="width: 200px">
                                            کدقرارداد
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="bgHead" colspan="2" title="Bid">
                                            تقاضا
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="bgHead" colspan="2" title="Ask">
                                            عرضه
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="bgHead" colspan="5" title="Traded Prices">
                                            قیمت های معامله شده
                                        </th>

                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="bgHead" title="Vol">
                                            حجم
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="bgHead" title="Price">
                                            قیمت-ریال
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="bgHead" title="Price">
                                            قیمت-ریال
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="bgHead" title="Vol">
                                            حجم
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="bgHead" title="قیمت اولین معامله انجام شدهFirst">
                                            اولین
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="bgHead" title="بالاترین قیمت معامله شدهHigh">
                                            بالاترین
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="bgHead" title="پایین ترین قیمت معامله شدهLow">
                                            پایین ترین
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="bgHead" colspan="2" title="قیمت آخرین معامله انجام شدهLast">
                                            آخرین
                                        </th>

                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="Spr" colspan="10"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody class="content">

                                    <tr>
                                        <!-- 1 -->
                                        <td rowspan="2">
                                            <b class="ng-binding">
                                                <button class="btn btn-default fa fa-area-chart" ng-click="myFFunc('lg',item.ContractCode)"></button>
                                                SAFOR99
                                            </b>

                                        </td>
                                        <td class="number bid ng-binding">0</td>

                                        <td class="number bid ng-binding">0</td>

                                        <td class="number ask ng-binding">0</td>

                                        <td class="number ask ng-binding">0</td>

                                        <td class="number ng-binding">93,000</td>

                                        <td class="number ng-binding">93,200</td>

                                        <td class="number ng-binding">87,900</td>

                                        <td class="number ng-binding">87,900</td>
                                        <td rowspan="7"><span class="btn-danger fa fa-close" ng-click="num=$index"></span></td>

                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <!-- 2 -->
                                        <td class="number bid ng-binding">0</td>

                                        <td class="number bid ng-binding">0</td>

                                        <td class="number ask ng-binding">0</td>

                                        <td class="number ask ng-binding">0</td>

                                        <td class="number" rowspan="2" title="تغییر نسبت به قیمت تسویه روزانه">
                                            <div ng-class="{ red: item.FirstTradedPriceChanges < 0,green: item.FirstTradedPriceChanges > 0 }" class="ng-binding green" style="">519</div>
                                            <div ng-class="{ red: item.FirstTradedPriceChangesPercent < 0,green: item.FirstTradedPriceChangesPercent > 0 }" class="ng-binding green">0.56%</div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="number" rowspan="2" title="تغییر نسبت به قیمت تسویه روزانه">

                                            <div ng-class="{ red: item.HighTradedPriceChanges < 0,green: item.HighTradedPriceChanges > 0 }" class="ng-binding green" style="">719</div>
                                            <span ng-class="{ red: item.HighTradedPriceChangesPercent < 0,green: item.HighTradedPriceChangesPercent > 0 }" class="ng-binding green">0.78%</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="number" rowspan="2" title="تغییر نسبت به قیمت تسویه روزانه" id="LWTPC">
                                            <div ng-class="{ red: item.LowTradedPriceChanges < 0,green: item.LowTradedPriceChanges > 0 }" class="ng-binding red" style="">
                                                -4,581
                                            </div>
                                            <span ng-class="{ red: item.LowTradedPriceChangesPercent < 0,green: item.LowTradedPriceChangesPercent > 0 }" class="ng-binding red">-4.95%</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td rowspan="2" title="تغییر نسبت به قیمت تسویه روزانه">
                                            <div ng-class="{ red: item.LastTradedPriceChanges < 0,green: item.LastTradedPriceChanges > 0 }" dir="ltr" class="ng-binding red" style="">
                                                -4,581
                                            </div>
                                            <span ng-class="{ red: item.LastTradedPriceChangesPercent < 0,green: item.LastTradedPriceChangesPercent > 0 }" dir="ltr" class="ng-binding red">-4.95%</span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <div title="وجه تضمین اولیه" class="ng-binding">
                                                2,000,000
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <!-- 3 -->
                                        <td class="number bid ng-binding">0</td>
                                        <td class="number bid ng-binding">0</td>
                                        <td class="number ask ng-binding">0</td>
                                        <td class="number ask ng-binding">0</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="number ng-binding" title="حداقل وجه تضمین">1,400,000</td>
                                        <!-- 4 -->

                                        <td animate-on-change="item.PersianOrdersDateTime" colspan="4" title="زمان آخرین به روزرسانی سفارشات" class="ng-binding"></td>

                                        <td colspan="4" title="نوع ارز" class="ng-binding">
                                            ریال/گرم
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <!-- 5 -->
                                        <td class="ng-binding"></td>

                                        <td class="DateTimeStyle" colspan="4" title="">--</td>

                                        <td animate-on-change="item.FirstTradedPriceTime" title="زمان انجام اولین معامله" class="ng-binding">10:30:00</td>

                                        <td colspan="2"></td>
                                        <td animate-on-change="item.LastTradedPriceTime" title="زمان انجام آخرین معامله" class="ng-binding">14:54:46</td>

                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="bgHead" title="Size">
                                            اندازه قرارداد
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="bgHead" colspan="4" title="قیمت تسویه روزانه">
                                            قیمت تسویه روزانه
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="bgHead" title="حجم معاملات انجام شده">
                                            حجم
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="bgHead ng-binding" colspan="2" title="ارزش معاملات انجام شده">
                                            ارزش (هزار ریال)
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="bgHead" title="موقعیت های تعهدی باز بازار">
                                            موقعیتهای باز
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="ng-binding">100 گرم</td>

                                        <td colspan="4"><span class="number ng-binding">92,481</span> (<span title="تاریخ قیمت تسویه روزانه" class="ng-binding"></span>)</td>

                                        <td class="number ng-binding" rowspan="2">63,197</td>

                                        <td colspan="2"><span class="number ng-binding">566,715,310</span></td>

                                        <td class="number">
                                            <div title="موقعیت های باز" class="ng-binding">58,497</div>
                                            <span title="تغییر نسبت به روز قبل" ng-class="{ red: item.OpenInterestsChanges < 0,green: item.OpenInterestsChanges > 0 }" class="ng-binding red" style="">-4,529</span>(<span ng-class="{ red: item.OpenInterestsChangesPercent < 0,green: item.OpenInterestsChangesPercent > 0 }" class="ng-binding red">-7.19 %</span>)
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="Spr" colspan="10"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>



                    </table>
```

Comment: you haven't specified what should be found by find method. I assume, therefore, you are getting entire response text displayed. If the actual values for the table are not present it is possible they are dynamically retrieved by xhr which you can search for in network tab of dev tools by refreshing page or possibly when clicking on a header.

Comment: @QHarr: I tried to grab all the site source and then find and specify what exactly I want, but when I see the `result` there is nothing about the content of the table. I also tried to using `xhr` but couldn't find a link to get the information directly from the server.

Comment: @QHarr: I have edited my question to show what exactly Im looking for.